# Display Products from External db in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, categories

I have a database in which some products and its categories. I want to display all this products to my site from database with all Magento functionalities. I am using Magento 1.9.x and MySql database. How can I do this? Does anyone have any ideas how I could do that? I am new to Magento

Comment: Hi user! You should find the appropriate tutorial.

Comment: I did not find any appropriate tutorial.